# Should demo and example apps be included in the same git repo as the project source code?

Tags: c#, git, gitflow

We have an in house developed and maintained Windows service written in C#. Other people and teams write plugins for this service.

Right now, the git repo for this service includes 3 'demo' apps that are meant to show plugin authors how to write plugins that interact with this service.

My job right now is to work on these demo apps, since right now they are very basic.

We are starting to use GitFlow, and I am having a hard time envisioning a workflow that makes sense. It seems odd to me that I would create Feature branches that eventually merge back to the Develop branch for this repo when I am not touching the source code for the actual Windows service project. I am just adding to and improving the Demo apps.

What is the correct way to do this? Separate repo for the demo apps? Submodules?

Answer (score 1):

A separate repo makes sense here.

The demo apps are independent of the service itself, and with a feature-centric workflow, enhancing the demo apps are more beneficial to the plugin authors than the service.

In addition, having the demo apps in their own repository enables the plugin authors to clone and extend the demo apps without having to pull down a mass of source code of which they don't need to know anything about.